# Which sites offer good tutorials for novices to improve?

Tags: opening, theory

Can anyone recommend sites that they have personally had experience with to be good for learning by novices? I play chess regularly, but I have never studied theory and while I am doing fairly well against most of the regulars I play against, there are several people who are able to have a clear advantage by the midgame.

I'd like to improve my openings by studying theory, but I've never looked at it before, so I wouldn't be helped much by a dry treatise on how to develop a pawn line against, for example, `1.d4`. I'm looking for an objective analysis of websites that teach the theoretical principles of openings, with good examples and a minimum of references to various famous openings.

Comment: here is a related question http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/free-learning-material , but they are mostly about improving tactics though :(

Comment: [ICC - The Internet Chessclub](http://www.chessclub.com) has a lot of material available to members including videos from GMs explaining popular openings and positions (I play there, but am otherwise un-associated with them).

Answer (score 2):

IMHO if you are struggling with the middle-game it makes more sense to study that particularly (as well as the endgame) instead of focusing on openings. I would advise you to learn to record your games in Algebraic Notation in order to learn from your mistakes (preferably with a stronger player). As far as online material you can use I can recommend [Novice Nook by Dan Heisman](http://www.chesscafe.com/archives/archives.htm#Novice%20Nook) and [Modern Ideas in Chess by Richard Rèti](http://www.openchessbooks.org/reti-mic/chapter1/combination.html)