# What are good YouTube channels for improving chess?

Tags: learning

What are good YouTube channels that help to improve our chess?

Channels which are analyzing their own games (Blitz, standard, OTB) or discussing tactics, strategies, etc.

I list some of these channels in the following.

Please share your favorites. Note that here we are interested in channels with learning material not channels with plenty amount of advertisements or fun.

Channels here are ordered arbitrarily with no preferences:

1. [IM Andrew Martin Chess Videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/YMChessMaster)
2. [John Bartholomew](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6hOVYvNn79Sl1Fc1vx2mYA)
3. [Chess Network](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCDOQrpqLqKVcTCKzqarxLg)
4. [Simon Williams](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClV9nqHHcsrm2krkFDPPr-g)
5. [Chess Club and Scholastic Center of Saint Louis](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCM-ONC2bCHytG2mYtKDmIeA)
6. [kingscrusher](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDUDDmslypVXYoUsZafHSUQ)
7. [GJ_Chess](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCji6ITCdOOmxUzd6R2TonZQ)

There are some other channels such as OnlineChessLessons, which are good but they are more introduction to openings. If one wants to go deep into something then have to pay for their videos but a simple blitz game analysis by IM or GM or even a normal good player can give more insight than an introduction to an opening X.

<sub>P.S0: Notice that I'm not looking for good online resources like this question: 
[Free learning material](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1335/free-learning-material), also not only for the beginner rather for advanced players. 
I want to be strict only on YouTube channels, as the other question does not cover even the channels that I've already subscribed.</sub>

Comment: I find John Bartholomew to be the most interesting and engaging. He explains his thoughts very well, and doesn't bore you to death with the tone of his voice, like many of the other more monotonic, slower speakers.

Even then, if they are well above your current rating, you will probably learn a lot from them, especially in the opening. Most of them tend to discuss weaknesses of particular lines made by the opponent and why.

Comment: @mojo1mojo2, I'm quite agree with you about John Bartholomew channel, he is quite better than me, explains almost deep without bothering about trivial thing, his voice is also nice and his speaking style as well. I was wondering if anyone found any other channel which is so good. it's always better to have different sources.

Comment: I like the content of ChessExplained. Presented very well, and he is genuinely interested in educating about his passion.

Comment: yes! Finegold rules :D

Comment: The Akobian videos from St. Louis chess club are good. If you look for Seirawan videos those are also pretty good.

Answer (score 14):

[ChessExplained](https://www.youtube.com/user/Chessexplained) is the channel of IM Cristof Sielecki. Most of the videos are him thinking aloud while playing blitz, and they provide excellent insight into the mind of an IM.

[IM Greg Shahade](https://www.youtube.com/user/GregShahadechess) has a similar channel as well. He is a bit more entertaining and less instructional than ChessExplained.

Comment: I upvote this for the first case not the second, Shahade's channel does not fit to the question.

Comment: They both analyze their blitz games, so I'm not sure why one is a relevant answer and the other isn't.

Comment: Shahade does not explain ideas, he is very focused on his game, he also gets very upset when he loses, maybe it's fun to watch but it's far from analysis. I think you already wrote the reason in your answer. e.g IM Daniel Rench also streams his bullet games, but only when he streams blitz game or tournaments, it's instructive, but he does not put those streams in his channel.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I agree that other streamers are more instructive.

Answer (score 8):

**Chess24** also seems to provide high-quality "Banter Blitz" videos (in English, German, and Spanish) which are quite useful for seeing the thought process of GM level play at 3 to 5-minute time controls.

Comment: Yes, at the time that I asked the question, chess24 wasn't like now. There were more promotions than  usefull chess materials.

Answer (score 7):

I like these 3:

- [Dereque Kelley's](https://www.youtube.com/user/KebuChess) channel on the openings goes through the key strategic ideas, for both sides, of many of the most popular mainlines
- [Claus Jensen's](https://www.youtube.com/user/clausjensencom) channel. I particularly liked his series on the exchange sacrifice
- [Chess.com's](https://www.youtube.com/user/wwwChesscom) channel, covering a wide range of chess topics from learning the rules to taking the initiative

Answer (score 7):

From one of my [previous answers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/7893/2792):

(1) [Majnu](https://www.youtube.com/user/Majnu2006/). Especially check out the "Chess middlegame training" and "Practical chess endgames" playlists. I like Majnu's videos because, not only is he a good player, but he also manages to explain ideas and plans in chess in a very simple manner. The concepts really stick in your mind, and you get to actually use them in your games. And from the way he explains things, you can see that he loves the game, which is also inspiring. I recommend Majnu highly (especially to beginners).

(2) [SeanGGodley](https://www.youtube.com/user/SeanGGodley/). Excellent analysis of famous games and players. The book "My system" by A. Nimzowitsch is considered to be one of the most important books in chess history, and Sean has a playlist dedicated to this book. Excellent and (pretty) detailed analysis make him one of my favourite YouTube channels for improving my game. Also, Sean is a great narrator in my opinion, and that makes it easier to follow his thoughts. However, Sean's videos are maybe too much for beginners.

(3) [thechesswebsite](https://www.youtube.com/user/thechesswebsite/). Many instructional videos on openings and traps, as well as other topics (like tournaments, players etc.). All in all, a very good channel to improve your game.

Comment: First one is not good for advanced players, e.g my rating is already pretty higher than Manjoo's rating so his analysis is not good for me specially blitz. But I think the second one is good in his OTB analysis.

Answer (score 5):

[IM Eric Rosen](https://www.youtube.com/user/RosenChess) has a YouTube channel in which he frequently posts stream supercuts and game analyses. His content is less focussed than other "learning resource" style channels, but his videos contain lots of information on different aspects of the game (particularly for lower level players).

His videos also happen to be very entertaining.

Answer (score 4):

For an analysis of master games, check out [agadmator's Chess Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/AGADMATOR).

He shows why the "obvious" move shouldn't be played, and then explains the more subtle, but better move.

He keeps it interesting by sometimes adding jokes in, and sometimes asks the viewer what the best move is.

This channel is mainly for expanding knowledge, not learning how to play.

Comment: This is the best channel.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to John Bartholomew and ChessNetwork, there are a ton of other interesting and entertaining channels.  I have about 30+ [YouTube chess channels](http://www.welearnchess.com/youtube-chess-channels/) listed on a page on my blog if you're interested in a brief explanation of each.

Comment: Welcome to Chess SE! While this is certainly interesting information, it's best to put it *here*, in case the link breaks. [Link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/295232) can get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with several posters above that John Bartholomew's channel is perhaps the best for somewhat experienced amateurs. His jovial personality, his communication skills and his teaching abilities have great appeal. Also, his natural style of positional play is something I think many maturing chess players can relate to.

Here are some others (not mentioned above) that deserve honorable mention for both entertainment value as well as learning:

- [Chessbrah](https://www.youtube.com/user/chessbrah/videos) (Eric Hansen)
- [PowerPlayChess](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMBATpFb--uLNAODOVWvCTA) (Daniel King)
- [Daniel Rensch](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6_wYihzxE2_7_GNPYKY42Q) (chess.com)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn specific openings, traps, and strategies, I suggest [TheChessWebsite](https://www.youtube.com/user/thechesswebsite)'s youtube channel.

Also, Kevin does a lot of analysis of games between Grand Masters both historical and modern, and even covers some games involving chess computers. I find that these are great for learning the subtle tactics of higher level play, and understanding how my own play is different. Also, it lets you see what the masters are actually looking at and the way in which they plan movements.

I would like to point out this is not a good channel for "learning" chess, however it is great for furthering and expanding your own knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a relatively unknown [channel of GM Tal Baron](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUzhSlr-PyawQXk2RzSWO7g).

Like the channels mentioned in dfan's answer, **GM Tal Baron** also commentates while playing Blitz.

Answer (score 1):

FedaMaster brings you guys one of the most entertaining and educative chess channel.

Chess stream videos regarding combinations, tactics, interesting blitz games against established GMs and also commentary on chess games are also available on this youtube channel.

Strongly Recommended to subscribe https://youtu.be/y38OFhyCKsA  :)

Answer (score 1):

I like chessgeek (I might be biased, as I am its owner). I made videos about many different topics (openings, strategy, analysis, ect), and make more every day!
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC99iLm4lpawrQrJJPV3qyJQ?view_as=subscriber) is the link if you are interested.

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! Linking to your own channel is OK in this case, but do note that we have some rules about [self promotion](/help/promotion) on this network.

Answer (score 0):

This new channel features quizes with a variety of types of moves as solutions,  not only tactical - making it a great resource for on the go training if you don't have time to play an entire game --  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpUUMhWg5GPD5ynP_vhnMJg